# Multiple RequestBody in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Service calls below MVC controller with following responses as payload using POST based on the result or error:

When valid result:

```
<document>
    <merchant>......</merchant>
</document>
```

and error:

```
<response>
    <error>Some error...</error>
</response>
```

Java Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "card/payment-response", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public int responsePayment(@RequestBody ResponseContext responseContext) {
    System.out.println(responseContext);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I read both using the same @RequestBody?

Comment: Do you set the appropriate `content-type` header in the request? Are Jackson and JAXB on the classpath?

Comment: I use spring boot. this lib already in a depedency.

Comment: Why you not go with JAX-RX implementation where you can read xml data as an Object of predefined class, the class might be one of 2  based on the xml packet you are sending. hence you can check the type Object class and handle accordingly, let me know if you want details example or this approach.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I add all needed header.

Comment: @ChetanVerma can you show me any example.

Comment: Modified the question to make it more readable and clear.